# How to run a method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set an age inside a method, and then display the age.

```
def set_age(new_age)
    @age = new_age
end

def get_age
    @age
end
```

How do I get this code to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the methods you created here. If these methods don't live inside a class you can do the following:

```
set_age(10)
get_age
```

If they live in a class:

```
your_object = YourClass.new
your_object.set_age(10)
your_object.get_age
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thank you, the top one worked fine but I had to do "puts get_age" for it to be displayed.

Comment: Good work! No question is dumb and good job with printing the result